# Changing font does not work

Tags: fonts

I would like to change to a font with sans serif (for example Helvetica or computer modern sans serif). The following code does not change the font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{
\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

\changefont{phv}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
THIS IS A TEST. 
this is a test.\\

\begin{tabular}{lr} \hline 
ABCD & 1234       \\
abcd & 1234,567   \\
UVWXY & 1,234,567 \\
uvwxy & 1,234,567 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get a pdf-file with serif. There are no errors and warnings. I'm using Windows 7, MikTex, TeXnicCenter. Does anyone have an idea why this does not work?

Comment: Your `\changefont` command will introduce 4 word-spaces at every point it is used, I suspect that you do not want that (you could use the standard `\usefont` command which is almost the same except takes an additional encoding argument, and doesn't have white space issues)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your method doesn't work because `\begin{document}` also issues `\normalfont`, so nullifying your font choice. You could place the command after `\begin{document}` or say

```
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{%
  \fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}
\AtBeginDocument{\changefont{phv}{m}{n}}
```

but this is an unneeded complication and

```
\AtBeginDocument{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{phv}{m}{n}}
```

would do exactly the same. However, I wouldn't recommend such an approach.

If you want your document to be in sans serif font, the best approach is to change the meaning of `\familydefault` to `\sfdefault`.

Then, instead of specifying the font family with a low level command like your `\changefont`, it's better to select the font with a higher level method:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[scale=.9]{tgheros} % or helvet
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
THIS IS A TEST.
this is a test.

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lr} \hline
ABCD & 1234       \\
abcd & 1234,567   \\
UVWXY & 1,234,567 \\
uvwxy & 1,234,567 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Don't use `\\` followed a blank line in order to have vertical space.

[image]